# Random array using LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, enumerable

I was reading an article on MSDN Magazine about using the [Enumerable class in LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700332.aspx) to generate a random array. The article uses VB.NET and I'm not immediately sure what the equivalent is in C#:

```
Dim rnd As New System.Random()
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100). _
    OrderBy(Function() rnd.Next)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Developer Fusion VB.Net to C# converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) says that the equivalent C# code is:

```
System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(r => rnd.Next());
```

For future reference, they also have a [C# to VB.Net converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/). There are [several other tools](http://www.dotnetspider.com/convert/Vb-To-Csharp.aspx) available for this as well.

Comment: edited to be the combination of everyone's.  this was top answer at the time.  I'm not playing favorites, just keeping it clean.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. Just for reference, this is James Curran's code.

Answer (score 5):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(r => rnd.Next());
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting: Hmmm, I'm getting: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

I initially thought this would be a bad idea since the sort algorithm will need to do multiple comparisons for the numbers, and it will get a different sorting key for the same number each time it calls the lambda for that number.  However, it looks like it only calls it once for each element in the list, and stores that value for later use.  This code demonstrates this:

```
int timesCalled = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();

List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(r =>
   {
       timesCalled++;
       return rnd.Next();
   }
).ToList();

Assert.AreEqual(timesCalled, 100);
```

Answer (score 4):

What about something far more easy...

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(c=> Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Best I can do off the top of my head without access to Visual Studio (crosses fingers):

```
System.Random rnd = New System.Random();
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(rnd => rnd.Next);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5), you could just use the builtin `Shuffle()` method:

```
IList<int> numbers = new ArrayList<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,100));
numbers.Shuffle();
```