# Linq method to return a random set of records

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, random, methods

I have this function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns an array of random articles, ID and titles only
/// </summary>
/// <param name="SectionID">Section ID to return</param>
/// <param name="Count">Number of articles to return</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public ArticleOverview[] RandomArticles(int SectionID, int Count)
{
    ArticleOverview[] ReturnLinks;

    // Pick a random tutorial and redirect to it
    using (MainContext db = new MainContext())
    {
        // Select rows
        var q = (from c in db.tblArticles where c.IsDeleted == false && c.SectionID == SectionID select new { c.ID, c.Title });
        int count = q.Count();
        int index = new Random().Next(count);
        var Articles = q.Skip(index).Take(Count);

        // Size array
        ReturnLinks = new ArticleOverview[Articles.Count()];

        int InsertIx = 0;
        foreach (var Rec in Articles)
        {
            ReturnLinks[InsertIx] = new ArticleOverview(Rec.ID, Rec.Title, SectionID);
            InsertIx++;
        }
    }

    return ReturnLinks;
}
```

There are two problems with this method:

- If it selects one of the last records, it will return *less* records than intended, IE if recordset count is 100 and we are selecting 10 records and it returns index 95 it will only return 5 records and not 10
- The returned records are ordered, they are not jumbled.  The returned records need to be randomised and not ordered as they exist sequentially in the database.

Thanks for any help!  I'm using SQL Server Express 2008 R2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random row from Linq to Sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql)

Comment: @Ahmad, thanks I saw that already and use that method, the problem is it's only good for returning a single record not a set.

Comment: are you sure? I believe you can use Marc's approach and use the [`Queryable.Take` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) to get multiple records: `dc.Customers.OrderBy(x => dc.Random()).Take(5)`. I'm fairly sure this is possible since I've played with that approach in the past. They return in random order first, then you `Take` N records that have already been randomized.

Comment: @Oh wow I'm dumb thanks!  I just didn't understand his answer but I get it now after reading more carefully, thank you and sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the method in [Random row from Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql) to do an `orderby ctx.Random()` and do a `.Take(sampleSize)` on the results instead of `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Dave, that's exactly what I'm doing right now, except the records return ordered which is what the question is about!

Comment: If you use the "orderby ctx.Random()" approach then all the items will be in a Random order.

Comment: No problem - I did have to edit my answer to add in the bit about using "orderby ctx.Random()" after I re-read it and realised it didn't make sense. :o.

Answer (score 0):

How random do you need the results to be?

Well you could select new anonymous random values from 'q' and afterwards order by that random number and select top count. The obvious drawback is that all articles would need to be read into memory instead of delegating the selection to db.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential issue is that the current method does not select each record with the same probability.  A simple way to see that is suppose that 9 of 10 records are desired.  The current method would have only a 10% chance of selecting the first record yet it would always select the 10th record.

It seems it would be better to generate a random set of record numbers (such as [described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254844/random-array-using-linq-and-c)).  Then use those to choose those entries from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Define Random class instance to have it "More random"

2 . Use the following code to select random elements

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, count).OrderBy(a => Rand.Next()).Take(resCount).Select(i => q[i]);
```