# C# method and table random numbers

Tags: c#

I've method which put the numbers 1 to 9  in a random order. Each number appears only once. The method should return an integer table.

This is my code which facing the wall, I ran out of ideas with this code.
I know that this code is 100% wrong.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int luvut = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            Console.WriteLine(luvut);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static int Kuuluuko(int luvut)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < luvut.Length; i++)
            {

                return;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So `Kuuluuko` is supposed to randomize them? What have you tried? Also if you compile this what errors do you get?

Comment: please explain in more details what you want to do, not clear question

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254844/random-array-using-linq-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

```
var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1,9).OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
```

Comment: Looking at the example code, I'm not sure just giving a working answer is going to be much help :)

Comment: can you please put the hole method code

Comment: @DannyChen: OP is a really newbie in C#, your code is great, but will this help him?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? Make a list, and remove the numbers from that list as you use them up. Like drawing numbers from a bowl or something like that :)

```
var numbers = new List<int>(new[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
var randomnumbers = new List<int>();
var rnd = new Random();
while( numbers.Count > 0 ){
  var index = rnd.Next(0, numbers.Count);
  randomnumbers.Add(numbers[index]);
  numbers.RemoveAt(index);
}
//randomnumbers now contain the random sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of errors and didn't even compile. Here is the code running and giving you what you expect:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] luvut = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        Console.WriteLine(Kuuluuko(luvut));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static int Kuuluuko(int[] luvut)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        return luvut[random.Next(0, luvut.Length)];
    }
}
```

Comment: is it? it still doesn't call the Kuuluuko method :)

Comment: ah, now it does! however, it still only returns one int from the list, rather than a reordered list.

Comment: @Hybrid: Yes, I missed the call to Kuuluuko (what that means in Finnish).