# How to choose a random element from an array in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2008, vba, random

I have created an array of Integer and want to choose a random element from it. How do I do that?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/254861/1080742

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
YourArray(New Random().Next(0,YourArray.Length-1))
```

Or separated out for more clarity:

```
Dim Rand as New Random()
Dim Index as Integer = Rand.Next(0, YourArray.Length - 1)

Dim SelectedValue = YourArray(Index)
```

Comment: An instance of the Random class has a function called "Next" that takes a min and max value as the range for a random number, in this case the range is 0 to your array's length minus one.  That number is then used as the index to the array, selecting whatever element is there.  I put it into one line, but you can separate it out for clarity.  I will update with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Make a random integer number in the range from `0` to `Len-1`, where `Len` is the length of your array. To make a random integer, use an instance of the `Random` class.

```
DIM rand As New Random
DIM idx as rand.Next(0, Len)
REM Now you can pick an element idx from the array
REM to get a random element.
DIM res as myArray(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rnd can get [0,1),then mutiple Your arraylength, you can get number between [0,YourArrayLength)

```
Randomize
Int(array.length* Rnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say that the accepted answer is incorrect.

This is the correct one

```
Dim Rand as New Random()
Dim Index as Integer = Rand.Next(0, YourArray.Length)

Dim SelectedValue = YourArray(Index)
```

Why?

Because the maximum value is exclusive. So if you won't to pick among 3 elements, for example, the maximum value should be 3, not 2.

```
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Returns a non-negative random integer.
    '
    ' Returns:
    '     A 32-bit signed integer that is greater than or equal to 0 and less than System.Int32.MaxValue.
    Public Overridable Function [Next]() As Integer
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Returns a random integer that is within a specified range.
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   minValue:
    '     The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.
    '
    '   maxValue:
    '     The **exclusive** upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater
    '     than or equal to minValue.
    '
    ' Returns:
    '     A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and **less than** maxValue;
    '     that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue
    '     equals maxValue, minValue is returned.
    '
    ' Exceptions:
    '   T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
    '     minValue is greater than maxValue.
```

I also tried. I tried to select one out of 3 elements and notice that only the first 2 elements get chosen. The third element is never chosen
[image]